# Assignment to a borrowed in RefCell

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, refcell

The following code gives me the "Assignment to borrowed a" error. Hows the compiler able to know that? Is the compiler special casing RefCell or is there something in the language that allows it to tell the compiler you have a borrowed value?

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let mut a = RefCell::new(A{a:5});
    let mut b = a.borrow_mut();
    a = RefCell::new(A{a:6});
}
```

Also, why does this code work which seems to be doing the exact same thing?

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let mut a = Box::new(A{a:5});
    let mut b = &mut a;
    a = Box::new(A{a:6});
}
```

Comment: I guess that the main issue is that `b` is a `RefMut`, which must not outlive the original `RefCell` it is pointing to. However, in the first example, you drop the `RefCell` while `b` is still valid.

In contrast, in your second example, `b` is a simple reference and, as you don't use it, the compiler is able to know that you are not breaking any rule when modifying `a`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is not special casing `RefCell`. But [`borrow_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut) has the following signature:

```rust
pub fn borrow_mut(&self) -> RefMut<'_, T>
```

So it returns a `RefMut` that keeps the `RefCell` borrowed while it is alive (because of the `'_`, that according to the [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html) rules borrows from `self`). So while it is alive, you cannot assign to the `RefCell` because it is borrowed.

The reason the second case with a mutable reference works is that since mutable references don't implement `Drop` (a more precise term is that they don't have a *drop glue*, that is, neither they implement `Drop` nor any of their fields (which is none for mutable references) has a drop glue, recursively), the compiler shortens the borrow and drop the reference early. But it cannot do that with the `RefMut` from the `RefCell` because it implements `Drop`, and thus early-dropping it would change program behavior.

Comment: "because it implements Drop, and thus early-dropping it would change program behavior" this was my main misconception. The answer was terrific, thank you.